# Automate formatting of the sheet headings to the all the other sheet using macro excel

Tags: excel, vba

As, I m new to macro. I want help in doing the below task.
 I want the heading formatting in a new sheet , but not copying it from another sheet, but by formatting the corresponding cells via the macro/script.

Comment: [Okay](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). [What have you tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:L50000").Copy

With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths

End With

Comment: That code simply is pasting the column formatting. What are you wanting to copy? The headers too?

Comment: yes, thats were I m stuck. Idk how to copy only the headings of a sheet into all the other sheets in a workbook.

Comment: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F1").Copy Worksheets("NewSheet").Range("A1:F1")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just to help if anyone else is looking for basic code to accomplish the task.

```
Sub CopyHeaderstosheets()

Dim wsX As Worksheet
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    For Each wsX In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If wsX.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
            ws1.Range("A1:F1").Copy
            With wsX
                .Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

                'Use this line if you don't want to paste the values
                '.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

                .Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
                .Rows(1).RowHeight = ws1.Rows(1).RowHeight
            End With
        End If
    Next wsX

Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I have 10 sheets in that workbook, I will be creating 25more sheets. I m trying to automate the headings of the sheets. So that I dont want to copy paste the same headings in the remaining sheets. Do I need to record the macro and copy paste your code , or how does i shoudl proceed with that. Please help me

Comment: if i try running this code, it says, compile error: invalid outside procedure

Comment: Please clarify; in your question comments you stated "to copy only the headings of a sheet into all the other sheets" but in today's comments you stated "I dont want to copy paste the same headings in the remaining sheets". What do you need help with? Also, if you don't place the above code inside `Sub Test()` and `End Sub` you will get that error.There are plenty of free online tutorials that you can go to and learn basic vba scripting. Do a Google search for "excel vba tutorial".

Comment: hi Gmalc. u misunderstood my previous comment. what i meant is..I badly want to automate the copying of heading using macro..so that I dnt need to copy them manually ( ctrl+c, ctrl+v).

Comment: hi Gmalc ,could you please tell me.. if i have something like this { ws1.Range("A1:L1, A2:L2").Copy } now how will i paste a2:l2 in the a2 of the new sheets

Comment: If you are just asking how to copy paste the header values (only) from sheet ws1 to ws2; the basic code would be `ws1.Range("A1:L2").Copy wsX.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues'